# Got an idea for a simple IT solution for a uni assignment. What's an appropriate way to estimate the cost of developing and maintaining this software?

Tags: software-development, pm-software, software

I have an idea for a simple IT solution that matches students in class to make study groups, it's for a uni assignment. What's an appropriate way to estimate the cost of developing and maintaining this software/solution?

The tension of the project is:

- I can do the matchmaking process with an excel spread sheet and saves so many hassles and costs
- But then the service would have limited scalability, need to have a lot of volunteers and/or pay staff just for this one simple task
- Limits other ideas for a "check-in" system which notifies each other what content people in the group has interacted with and lectures reviewed.
- Cost seems to bottom out once initial investment is made but is still followed by maintenance cost

Comment: Are you a student or a teacher at the university? Do you have any programming skills?

Comment: There are (generally) three ways to estimate - by analogy (find similar software), by parameter (measure it) and by expert.  Given that you're asking, I assume that the second and third options are unworkable.  You probably want to estimate by finding similar software and basing the estimate on analogous values

Comment: @Bogdan Yes i am. We just had an idea to match people into groups and have that be a university service. Wasn't so so sure what's a fair and reasonable way for us to say it would cost.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you research Total Cost of Ownership (TCO). You'll find quite a few checklists and examples to give your some ideas. You could start here:

https://www.cio.com/article/3005705/calculating-the-total-cost-of-ownership-for-enterprise-software.html